# Função date retornando mês em pt-br

Tags: php

Tem alguma forme da função `date` retornar o mês atual em pt-br?

Exemplo:
["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/LAlm9x)

strftime — Formata uma hora/data de acordo com as configurações locais

`%b` traz o mes abreviado     https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo strftime('%b', strtotime('today'));
```

> Caso deseje apenas configurar as datas basta alterar   `LC_ALL` para  `LC_TIME`

A função [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php) é responsável por especificar o tipo de localidade desejada para realizar operações de uma categoria. O primeiro parâmetro representa a categoria de operações, e deve valer uma das constantes abaixo:

```
LC_COLLATE - para especificar as regras da localidade para comparação de textos.
LC_CTYPE - para especificar as regras da localidade para classificação/conversão de caracteres.
LC_MONETARY - para especificar a notação monetária de uma localidade.
LC_NUMERIC - para especificar a notação numérica de uma localidade.
LC_TIME - para especificar a notação de data/tempo de uma localidade.
LC_MESSAGES - para especificar o idioma das mensagens de log.
LC_ALL - para especificar a localidade para todas as categorias.
```

O segundo parâmetro deve ser uma string, com o nome da localidade de acordo com o sistema operacional. Isso porque a função setlocale utiliza as definições de localidade definidas no servidor, inclusive seu nome.

Por exemplo, no Linux, podemos instalar as definições de localidade para português do Brasil e modificar as regras de localidade com a string "pt_BR", enquanto, no Windows, a string pode ser "Portuguese_Brazil". O charset também é importante, já que algumas operações dependem dele.

Podemos passar um terceiro, quarto, quinto parâmetro, etc. para a função setlocale, especificando várias localidades possíveis. A primeira a ser encontrada pelo servidor é utilizada. Veja o exemplo:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8', 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.