# Usar o setlocale apenas para a date

Tags: php

Bom estou usando o `setlocale` para que o php me retorne o nome do mês em PT-BR. O problema e que esta afetando os cálculos do sistema. O php esta colocando uma virgula no ligar do ponto.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

echo strftime('%b', strtotime("-1 month"));

echo "<br><br>";

echo 123.33 - 111.11;
```

No exemplo que postei ele me retorna:

```
Mai

12,22
```

Sendo que el tem que me retornar:

```
Mai

12.22
```

Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Não trabalho com PHP e posso estar errado, mas olhando a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) me parece ser só alterar o `LC_ALL` para `LC_TIME`

Comment: De onde vem esses numeros? Você pode usar a função $suaVariavel=str_replace(",",".",$suaVariavel);

Comment: Editei a resposta da sua pergunta anterior para sanar esse problema  veja em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210453/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-retornando-m%C3%AAs-em-pt-br/210456#210456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo o [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210572/usar-o-setlocale-apenas-para-a-date/210635?noredirect=1#comment430535_210572) do Leandro Godoy Rosa, de acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), há:

- `LC_ALL` *for all of the below*
- `LC_COLLATE` *for string comparison, see strcoll()*
- `LC_CTYPE` *for character classification and conversion, for example strtoupper()*
- `LC_MONETARY` *for localeconv()*
- `LC_NUMERIC` *for decimal separator (See also localeconv())*
- `LC_TIME` *for date and time formatting with strftime()*
- `LC_MESSAGES` *for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)*

Ou seja, ao utilizar `LC_ALL` estará afetando todos os itens descritos, incluindo o `LC_NUMERIC`, que define a formatação dos números. Caso queira que apenas a configuração de datas sefa afetada, basta alterar para `LC_TIME`:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
```

Comment: O que está errado?  https://ideone.com/RVrqJL

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo O ideone não permite a alteração do `setlocale`. Teste localmente e verás funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: valeu, testei localmente. Mais uma informação para a minha base de conhecimento essa do ideone não permitir alteração do setlocale. Por isso que não tinha colocado na minha resposta.